# C# returns error "Cannot implicitly convert type 'X' to 'Y'"

Tags: c#

Here is the code I'm trying to use to connect with the external

```
string result = string.Empty;
```

Here is the code I'm trying to use to connect with the external but I'm getting this error.

```
string result = string.Empty; string url = "https://WebapiServer/api/Controller";

using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient()) {
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url);

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode) {
        result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(); //country;
    }
}

return Json(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(result));
```

And this is the error I'm getting:

```
"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"Cannot implicitly
convert type
'System.Web.Http.Results.JsonResult<Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject>'
to 'System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult'"
```

Comment: I'm using ASP.Net MVC and I would like to consume a public web api that returning data in Json format

Comment: you are mixing up two jsonresult definitions.

Comment: I don't get why you would Deserialize the result just to re serialize it into JSON again
i think you could have returned `result` directly

Comment: If `result` is already json (since you deserialize it), why don't you simply return it, instead of serializing a deserialized result? It seems as a very unnecessary operation to first deserialize it, then serialize it. Or is this just a finicky way of validating that what you got is proper json?